# What happens if I redirect from a wordpress plugin activation hook?

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-rest-api, woocommerce-rest-api

Imagine a simple plugin with the following code:

```
register_activation_hook(__FILE__, $this, 'on_plugin_activate');

public function on_plugin_activate(){
   wp_redirect("https://www.google.com");
   exit();
}
```

Will this cancel activation of the plugin?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, this will not activate the plugin as before activate plugin process completes it will redirect to google.com